# view.bounds.size.height -vs- view.bounds.height -- Any Difference?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I've noticed that in IOS X-Code using (Swift 4.0), I can ask for the height of a view, V, in at least these two ways:

```
V.bounds.size.height
```

and...

```
V.bounds.height
```

Is there any actual difference between these two?

I did the option-click thing (which give different definitions, but don't explain any practical difference or reason for one over the other)... and stackoverflow... but here on stackoverflow, all the results are discussing the difference between *bounds* and *frame*... which is NOT what I'm asking.

Comment: No ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`V.bounds.height` is only a GET Property. You Can't set a value for this property.

Example:

```
self.view.bounds.height = 5
```

This error message results...

> Cannot assign to property: 'height' is a get-only property

If you want to assign a value to this property, then you can write...

```
self.view.bounds.size.height = 5
```

So you can set value to this object. Have a look at [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNaE8.png)

Comment: There is also another small difference, these getters give you the normalized values of the `CGRect`. See my answer below. :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the fact that `view.bounds.height` is readonly, there is another difference: if you have negative width/height, `view.bounds.height` will return you the normalized value (the positive one), while `view.bounds.size.height` will return the real value. These getters are the equivalent of the `CGRectGetWidth()` `CGRectGetHeight()` from Obj-C. All these getters from `CGRect` struct (`widht`, `height`, `minX`, `minY`...) are returning the normalized values of the `CGRect`'s dimensions and they are recommended in case you want to use them in frame computations.

Answer (score 1):

There is small difference. `view.bounds.height` is a shortcut. You cannot edit it :

`view.bounds.height = 150` won't work, but `view.bounds.size.height = 150` will.

Answer (score 1):

Actually `V.bounds.size.height`, **height** have both get-set property and where as in `V.bounds.height`, **height**  is only getter property and it always return you height of the rectangle.

For the getter perspective both are same.